# Microsoft TTF fonts (like Tahoma) refuse to display on Centos 6.2

Tags: fonts, centos, truetype-fonts, centos-6

I've followed the instructions here:
http://blog.whatgeek.com.pt/2011/11/install-core-fonts-centos-6/

All of the `msttcorefonts` fonts are extracted into the `/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts` directory and are correctly owned by root. I even `chmod`'ed them to 777 to make sure this isn't a permission issue.

Yet, while the fonts show up in the fonts selection dialog, they don't actually display. Namely, Tahoma, when selected, doesn't actually show up as Tahoma, but as the regular Centos 'Sans' font. Why?!

[image: Sans]

[image: Tahoma regular]

[image: Tahoma Bold]

Comment: You might need to log out and log back in for font changes to take effect.

Comment: I've restarted about eight times. :(